# spring boot kafka session.timeout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In my springBoot project, I use `kafka` listening message, like this:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = Constants.ARTICLE_TOPIC, groupId = "articleConsumer")
private void receiveArticle(String content) {
    try {
        if (null != content) {
            messageHandler.handleMessage(content);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("===Kafka[Article]Consumer error===", e);
    }
}

@KafkaListener(topics = Constants.BUSINESS_TOPIC, groupId = "businessConsumer")
private void receiveBusiness(String content) {}

@KafkaListener(topics = Constants.RULE_TOPIC, groupId = "ruleConsumer")
private void receiveRule(String content) {}
```

and the `handleMessage` method is:

```
public void handleMessage(String msg) throws Exception {
    logger.error("---------handle message-------------");
    ...code handle message...
}
```

I have a `breakpoint` in the `logger.error("---------handle message-------------");`

when I received a `msg`, the program will stop in the `logger.error("---------handle message-------------");` and after `10s`, I press the `F9`(cancel the `breakpoint` meanwhile) so the program will run.

the `msg` will be handled `20s-30s`.

my confusion is when I have `breakpoint` and wait more than `10s`, I will get the `kafka` error, the `breakpoint` will stop the `kafka` send the `heartbeat`?

the error is:

```
2019-10-26 14:34:49,710 ERROR [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (:) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=businessConsumer] Offset commit failed on partition medium_business_status-0 at offset 0: The coordinator is not aware of this member.
2019-10-26 14:34:49,710 ERROR [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-0-C-1] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (:) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=ruleConsumer] Offset commit failed on partition rules-0 at offset 0: The coordinator is not aware of this member.
2019-10-26 14:34:49,710 WARN  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (:) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=businessConsumer] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {medium_business_status-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=0, metadata=''}} failed: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
2019-10-26 14:34:49,710 WARN  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-0-C-1] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (:) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=ruleConsumer] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {rules-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=0, metadata=''}} failed: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
2019-10-26 14:34:49,711 WARN  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-0-C-1] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (:) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=ruleConsumer] Synchronous auto-commit of offsets {rules-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=0, metadata=''}} failed: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
2019-10-26 14:34:49,711 WARN  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (:) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=businessConsumer] Synchronous auto-commit of offsets {medium_business_status-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=0, metadata=''}} failed: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

`businessConsumer` and `ruleConsumer` have nothing to do with handle the `msg`, meanwhile they have no message, but they have error, and the `articleConsumer`
error is:

```
2019-10-26 14:34:50,237 INFO  [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | articleConsumer] internals.AbstractCoordinator (:) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=articleConsumer] Discovered group coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-10-26 14:34:53,500 INFO  [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | articleConsumer] internals.AbstractCoordinator (:) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=articleConsumer] Attempt to heartbeat failed for since member id consumer-6-944e8b2d-7519-461c-99e6-e957f9eb97f6 is not valid.
```

I know `kafka` properties:

```
 `session.timeout.ms = 10000
  max.poll.interval.ms = 300000`
```

the `session.timeout.ms` used for judge `consumer` is alive;

the `max.poll.interval.ms` is the maximum time between two `poll()`.

the springboot version is `<version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>`

Comment: You should not get a rebalance unless you pause for 5 minutes; try looking at the server logs to see if it has any clues; also try turning on DEBUG logging on the client.

Comment: @GaryRussell I pause just `20s`, and get kafka rebalance; I'm curious why `businessConsumer` and `ruleConsumer` rebalance, but `articleConsumer` not.